# How to use generic param with Lambdas

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Assume we have the following code without Lambdas:

```
doSomething.consumer("someString", new Handler<Message<JsonObject>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(Message<JsonObject> event) {
                    //do some code                         
                }
            });
```

How could I convert this code using Lambdas and using the Lambda's param as

```
 Handler<Message<JsonObject>>
```

This is what the consumer method looks like:

```
<T> MessageConsumer<T> consumer(String address, Handler<Message<T>> handler);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this to define what `T` is

```
doSomething.<JsonObject>consumer("someString", event -> { /* do some code */ });
```

or define what type `event` is

```
doSomething.consumer("someString", (Message<JsonObject> event) -> { /* do some code */ });
```

or define what type you expect the Handler to be.

```
doSomething.consumer("someString", (Handler<Message<JsonObject>>) 
                                   (event -> { /* do some code */ }));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MessageConsumer<JsonObject> consumer = 
    doSomething.consumer("someString", event -> {
        // some code
    });
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation to what this code does/how it works? Code can often by difficult to understand without annotation.

Comment: I'm not sure what to explain, in fact, because I'm not sure what the OP's problem is. This is just a lambda implementing a functional interface.

Comment: Well, in the question’s code, the result value of `consumer(…)` is not used. Therefore, there’s no target type for inferring the lambda’s type. Assigning the result to a variable provides a target type…

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to re-write the handler using lambda's? Could be something like the following

```
<T> MessageConsumer<T> consumer(String address, Function<Message<T>, Void> function);
```

and instead of

```
doSomething.consumer("someString", new Handler<Message<JsonObject>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Message<JsonObject> event) {
                //do some code                         
            }
        });
```

you could write

```
doSomething.consumer("someString", message -> null);
```

Comment: That is unnecessary. Handler is already a functional interface, and can thus be written as a lambda expression. BTW, the appropriate standard functional interface would be `Consumer<Message<T>>`.